# What are some safe and ethical ways to dispose rinse water used to clean up lead contamination jobs?

Tags: lead

I'm researching lead paint removal and cleanup, and I understand the need to seal off the room with plastic and tape. I also understand that a final cleanup is to be carried out some time after 4 to 24 hours after the removal job. The prevailing recommendation is to wash or mop the floor using rags and separate buckets for wash water solution and rinse water, and to seal off your cleaning materials in a bag. What I haven't been able to find is a satisfactory method to dispose of the rinse water resulting from that cleanup.

In [this literature from the state of Maine](https://www.maine.gov/dhhs/mecdc/environmental-health/eohp/lead/documents/leadtipsheet2.pdf), they have you wash your lead contaminated areas and then to pour the rinse water into the toilet. It occurs to me that this is deferring the lead contamination to sewage treatment, which seems much less than ideal.

Comment: Why would that be less than ideal? Presumably water treatment plants have the ability to remove contaminants from water. It would be one thing if you poured it down a storm drain that doesn't go through water treatment, but if Maine recommends this, it's presumably because they can manage lead removal from water much better than you can.

Comment: Dilution at the treatment plant would reduce the concentration by orders of magnitude regardless. Keep in mind that the goal is to reduce lead to a minimum practical level, not eliminate it. For example, "lead free" plumbing fittings contain the minimum amount of lead required for manufacturing rather than zero. Also, cars have migrated to unleaded fuel but nobody has found a viable alternative to leaded aviation gas despite a lot of looking. (So virtually every plane with a piston engine spews small amounts of lead in its exhaust.)

Answer (score 1):

Let the water evaporate and then dispose of the bucket in a plastic garbage bag.